# Can query parameter start with "&" instead of "?"?

Tags: http, url, query-string

It came to my attention that marketing in our company is using `&` to start query parameter like this: `https://www.example.com/something&m`. It is used mainly to track source of users for analytics. They say they have been using it like this for a while.

I know this is not the standard way of defining query parameters, but it seems to work.

Why does it work? Is that a possible way of writing query parameters?

Comment: It might work for some particular combination of software, who knows why, possibly co-operating bugs: but you're right, it's wrong. `&` is for separating query parameters *after* the initial `=`. No reason not to get it right.

Comment: Does it really work? How does your company parse the query string? From [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/search), it must start with `?`.